# Get Value of Week Input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to save the value of a week Input in a Variable.
Additionally, I want to output it in a span.

I tried this:

```
<input type="week" name="week" id="week-selector">
<span id="kalenderwoche"></span>

var kw = document.getElementById("week-selector").value;
document.getElementById("kalenderwoche").innerHTML = kw;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. You just need an event handler

Here I made one that can be reused on load in case the selector has a value already

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page has loaded
  const kw = document.getElementById("kalenderwoche");
  const ws = document.getElementById("week-selector");
  let kwValue; // you wanted to save it for later?
  const setValue = () => kwValue = kw.textContent = ws.value || "";
  ws.addEventListener("input", setValue)
  setValue(); // initialise
  console.log(kwValue); // saved value
});
```

```html
<input type="week" name="week" id="week-selector" value="2022-W50" />
<span id="kalenderwoche"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add eventListener to week input

```js
var kw = document.getElementById("week-selector")
kw.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  console.log("e=>>>>", e.target)
  document.getElementById("kalenderwoche").innerHTML = e.target.value;
})
```

```html
<input type="week" name="week" id="week-selector">
<span id="kalenderwoche"></span>
```

Comment: If you click `[<>]`  you can make a snippet

Comment: is the above code solves your problem?

Comment: Not my question. I already gave a more complete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74687482/295783)

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="week" name="week" id="week-selector">
<span id="kalenderwoche"></span>

<script>

document.getElementById("week-selector").addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById("kalenderwoche").innerHTML = this.value
}) 
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```